# DIrigir el trafico de un Bridge a una la Interfaz publica de la maquina

Tags: linux, vps, networking, iptables

Tengo un pequeño problema con IPtables, lo tengo un poco abandonado y no consigo acabar de dar con la solucion, en mi VPS, tengo 2 interfaces, una interfaz eth0 ( Con IP publica ) y una interfaz virbr0 ( Bridge 192.168.122.0/24 ) desde el cual, le doy conectividad a mis diferentes contenedores LXC.

La preugnta es, como puedo redirigir el trafico del bridge virbr0 a la interfaz publica eth0? No acabo de dar con la regla/s de IPtables correcta/s.

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque esto es un caso de servidores, ajeno a la programación

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que tienes que permitir input en las 2 interfaces y permitir forward en el bridge:

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i virbr0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i virbr0 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu aportacion! Lo probare, aun que creo que hacer imputs i forwards en si, ya lo he provado junto a alguna regla masquerade.